# Как в JS выйти из цикла while?

Tags: javascript

Как в данном случае выйти из цикла while или switch? (не уверен где именно, новичок только начал изучать язык)

```
let amount = prompt('Скільки чисел ви хочете порахувати?')

let zero = 0
let result = 0


while (amount === null || amount === '' || amount.replace (/\d/g, '').length || amount <= 1) {
    amount = prompt('Введіть будь ласка число більше або дорівнює 2!');
}

while (zero < amount) {
    let number = +prompt('1')
    let action = prompt('Яку математичну операцію хочете провести?')

        while (action!== '+' && action!== '-' && action!== '*' && action!== '/') {
            action = prompt('Яку математичну операцію хочете провести?');
        }
    switch (action) {
        case "+":
            result = result + number;
            break;
        case "-":
            result = result - number;
            break;
        case "*":
            result = result * number;
            break;
        case "/":
            result = result / number;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    amount++
}
alert(result)
```

Comment: ...выход - break

Comment: Вроде написал но все равно не прерывается((

Comment: смотря где писал.... break в свитче не выходит из цикла, а вот вне свитча но внутри цикла - выходит))

Comment: Работает))
Но теперь в результат выводит только одно число

Comment: ещё можно метку поставить и делать выход на неё  ..... break labelName;  (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

Comment: " выводит только одно число " --- так надо break ставить при каком-то нужном условии